# How can I tell if a page is SSL in ASP?

Tags: ssl, asp-classic

How do I tell if a page is SSL'd in "classic" ASP? I can't use Javascript because what I'm outputting is the results of a `<noscript>` tag.

This can't be changed or modified in IIS. It has to be in the script file itself.

- https://example.com/something.asp should say YES
- http://example.com/something.asp should say NO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to get this info via

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

I used this to change image links to https to avoid weird IE messages:

```
<%
dim socket
If Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") = "on" then 
socket = "https"
else
socket = "http"
End if
%>
```

Then

```
 <img src="<%response.write(socket)%>://website.com/images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo" />
```

Comment: Sean, have you discovered that you can do `<img src="//website.com/images/logo.png" />` to achieve the same effect? It will use the same protocol as the referring page.

Comment: In addition to Michael's comments, they're not "weird IE Messages".  They are informing the user that they while they are accessing the site via https, some resources (such as your images), are being served up non-securely.

Comment: @LarryBud, this is true IE is not doing anything unintentional, thanks for the correction.  I guess it's just my true feelings for IE coming out ;-)